# Bootstrap macro in SAS

Tags: macros, sas, histogram, bootstrapping

I started to learn `%macro` in SAS and now I'm trying to implement simple bootstrap with histogram as an output.

```
/*Create K data sets(vectors)*/
%macro datasets(K);
    %do i=1 %to &K;
        data indata&i;
            %do j = 1 %to 50;
             x=(rand('normal',2,9));
            output;
            %end;
        run;
    %end;   
%mend datasets;

%datasets(3);

/*Bootstrap and hist*/
%macro boot (data,res);
    %do i=1 %to &res;
        %let x = (sample(&data,50));
        %let m = (mean(&x));
    %end;
    proc iml;
        read &m into A;
        create DataM from A;
        append from A;
        close Data1;
    quit;
    proc univariate data=Data1;
    histogram m;
    run;
    %mend boot;
%boot(Indata1,100);
```

It doesn't work and I can't understand why. Can you point me the mistake?

Comment: What do you expect to happen here:         `%let x = (sample(&data,50));
        %let m = (mean(&x));` I expect that isn't working the way you expect. It simply creates macro variables and doesn't do any sampling or calculations.

Comment: @Reeza I've tried to do it without `%let` and it doesn't work too.

Comment: What did you expect to happen in those steps? Also, see this paper for references on how to bootstrap in SAS: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/183-2007.pdf

Comment: @Reeza In this step I want to resample the vector with replacement and calculate mean for each sample. Then to draw the histogram of those means.

Comment: To sample you need to use PROC SURVEYSELECT and to calculate means you need to use PROC MEANS. If you want to use IML you need to first create matrices and then sample, calculate mean. You can see Rick Wicklin's book on sampling/simulation for more details on that methodology.

Comment: The whole point is to write bootstrap (resampling steps)  by using %macro and function `%do`.

Comment: You can use a hammer for a thumbtack but that doesn't mean you should. That being said, the answer is the same, you need to use proc surveyselect to generate a sample and proc means to generate mean. Your mixing proc iml and sas base. Is that on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned use Proc SurveySelect and Proc Means. You can select all 100 samples in one Proc SurveySelect and then apply Proc Means with a BY statement to calculate the means in one step. Macro's don't add anything to the solution here.

I'm posting both solutions - the macro solution does take longer as well.

```
*Without macro;
proc surveyselect data=indata1 out=rsample method=srs n=50 reps=100;
run;

proc means data=rsample noprint;
by replicate;
var x;
output out=Data1 mean(x)=m;
run;

proc univariate data=Data1;
histogram m;
run;

*Macro solution;

%macro boot(data, res);
%do i=1 %to &res;

%*Currently pulls the same sample every time but you can fix that part;
proc surveyselect data=&data out=x method=srs n=50 reps=1 seed=343434;
run; 

proc means data=x noprint;  
var x;
output out=m mean(x)=m;
run;

proc append base=DataM data=m;
run;

%end;

%mend;

%boot(Indata1,10);
```

Comment: I have tried different ways to change the seed (as function of do loop), but it still pulls the same sample.

Comment: Post a new question. Changing the seed in proc surveyselect should change your sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use PROC SURVEYSELECT to generate bootstrap samples then do bootstrap analysis by Replication (a variable created by SURVEYSELECT).  Your macro idea will be far too slow.

Comment: The whole point is to write bootstrap by using %macro. I did the same with R and SAS, but now I want to write it with %macro. For now speed of the code isn't important for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will help if we outline some of the ways that the posted macro code does NOT work.  If nothing else then as examples of things to avoid.

If the first macro , `%datasets()`, you are using a macro `%DO` loop where you should use a normal data step `DO` loop.  Also make sure to define your local macro variables as local. This will prevent the macro from modifying the value of an existing macro variable with the same name.

```
/*Create K data sets(vectors)*/
%macro datasets(K);
  %local i ;
  %do i=1 %to &K;
    data indata&i;
       do j = 1 to 50;
         x=(rand('normal',2,9));
         output;
       end;
       drop j;
    run;
  %end;   
%mend datasets;
```

In the second macro you have a `%DO` loop that does nothing.

```
%do i=1 %to &res;
  %let x = (sample(&data,50));
  %let m = (mean(&x));
%end;
```

You repeat the exact same `%LET` statements multiple times. The result does not change since the loop variable `i` is not referenced at all.  If you called the macro with `data=indata1` then the result of the two statements will be that X=`(sample(indata1,50))` and that M=`(mean((sample(indata1,50))))`.  I think that perhaps you intended that the strings `sample` and `mean` might take some action, but since they have no macro triggers (`&` or `%`) they are just streams of characters to the macro processor.

I am not an expert on IML, but those statements also do not look like they are doing much.